# IOptionsSnapshot with nested values: Cannot create instance of type because it is either abstract or an interface

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I'm developing a .NET 7 web application using clean architecture with the following 3 projects:

- Core (Entities, Interfaces, etc.)
- Infrastructure (contains an API to get some data from a third party source, etc.)
- Web (Controllers, ViewModels, etc)

In the Infrastructure Project I have a class that accesses an external API. I want to pass some options to this class, which currently looks like this:

```
public class MyApiAccessor : IMyApiAccessor
{
    private readonly IMyApiOptions _myApiOptions;

    public MyApiAccessor (private readonly IMyApiOptions _myApiOptions)
    {
        _myApiOptions = myApiOptions;
    }

    public void GetDataFromApi()
    {
        // implementation details, _myApiOptions is used in here
    }
}
```

**Web Project appSettings.json**

As you can see, the settings are split in two hierarchical levels. I want it explicitly to be like this.

```
  "MyApiSettings":
  {
    "FirstMainSetting": 11, 
    "SecondMainSetting": 12

    "SubSettings":
    {
      "FirstSubSetting": 21,
      "SecondSubSetting": 22,
      "ThirdSubSetting": 23
    },

    "MoreSubSettings":
    {
      "FourthSubSetting": 24,
      "FifthSubSetting": 25,
      "SixthSubSetting": 26
    }
  }
```

**Core Project Interfaces**

```
public interface IMyApiOptions
{
    public int FirstMainSetting { get; set; }
    public int SecondMainSetting { get; set; }
    
    // Note that here I'm using the Interfaces, 
    // since the Core Layer doesn't know about the according implementations
    public ISubSettingsOptions SubSettings { get; set; }
    public IMoreSubSettingsOptions MoreSubSettings { get; set; }
}

public interface ISubSettingsOptions
{
    public int FirstSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int SecondSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int ThirdSubSetting { get; set; }
}

public interface IMoreSubSettingsOptions
{
    public int FourthSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int FifthSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int SixthSubSetting { get; set; }
}
```

**Web Project Option Classes** (implement the interfaces mentioned above)

```
public class MyApiOptions : IMyApiOptions
{
    public int FirstMainSetting { get; set; }
    public int SecondMainSetting { get; set; }

    public ISubSettingsOptions SubSettings { get; set; }
    public IMoreSubSettingsOptions MoreSubSettings { get; set; }
}

public class SubSettingsOptions : ISubSettingsOptions
{
    public int FirstSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int SecondSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int ThirdSubSetting { get; set; }
}

public class MoreSubSettingsOptions : IMoreSubSettingsOptions
{
    public int FourthSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int FifthSubSetting { get; set; }
    public int SixthSubSetting { get; set; }
}
```

**Web Project Program.cs**

Here I get the config section, bind it to MyApiOptions and register the dependency with IMyApiOptions.

```
// [Using Statements]

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// [Add various services (e.g. MVC)]
// [Configure various dependency resolutions] 

// Configure the options class
builder.Services.Configure<MyApiOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyApiSettings"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyApiOptions>(x => x.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<MyApiOptions>>().Value);

var app = builder.Build();

// [Use static files, register routes, etc.]

app.Run();
```

However, once I run the application, I obtain the following exception:
*System.InvalidOperationException: "Cannot create instance of type 'MyProject.Core.Interfaces.ISubSettingsOptions' because it is either abstract or an interface."*

Does anybody have an idea, how I can solve this issue? It looks like this is caused by both `ISubSettingsOptions` and `IMoreSubSettingsOptions` in the `IMyApiOptions` class which can't be resolved, but since `IMyApiOptions` is in the Core Layer (to be accessible also from the Infrastructure Layer which references ist), I wouldn't know how I could adapt the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add initialization of those properties. Then `MyApiAOptions` class will still fully implement the interface, but DI container will be able to create its instances.

```cs
    public class MyApiOptions : IMyApiOptions
    {
        public int FirstMainSetting { get; set; }
        public int SecondMainSetting { get; set; }

        public ISubSettingsOptions SubSettings { get; set; } = new SubSettingsOptions();
        public IMoreSubSettingsOptions MoreSubSettings { get; set; } = new MoreSubSettingsOptions();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuration binder requires "concrete" types to be able to construct and bind them. You can workaround by removing setters from the interface and using [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```cs
public interface IMyApiOptions
{

    // ...
    public ISubSettingsOptions SubSettings { get; }
    public IMoreSubSettingsOptions MoreSubSettings { get; }
}

public class MyApiOptions : IMyApiOptions
{
    public int FirstMainSetting { get; set; }
    public int SecondMainSetting { get; set; }

    public SubSettingsOptions SubSettings { get; set; }
    public MoreSubSettingsOptions MoreSubSettings { get; set; }
    
    ISubSettingsOptions IMyApiOptions.SubSettings => SubSettings;
    IMoreSubSettingsOptions IMyApiOptions.MoreSubSettings => MoreSubSettings;
}
```